# Testing React Js Root Component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, webpack, mocha.js

I am exporting the react js root component as below

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

I am importing this component as below in my mocha test file

```
import HomePage from '../components/study/HomePage';
```

I am creating the component in the test file as below

```
beforeEach(() => {
    const _store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
                  <Provider store={_store}>
                    <HomePage />
                  </Provider>
                );
});
```

I am getting the below error when I run the tests

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
        at invariant (test-entry.js:4563:15)

Adding entire Homepage Component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { Paginate } from ‘pageGul’; //Custom Package
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import HomeListPage from './HomeListPage';
import PageHeader from '../common/PageHeader';
import * as HomeActions from '../../actions/HomeActions';
import * as constants from '../../constants/uiConstants';


class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    alert('props ' + JSON.stringify(props));
    alert('context ' + JSON.stringify(context));
    this.state = {
      paginate: {}
    };
    this.setPageNumberTextInput = this.setPageNumberTextInput.bind(this);
    this.getPage = this.getPage.bind(this);
    this.resetPageNumberTextInput = this.resetPageNumberTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  getPage(params) { // eslint-disable-line
    return this.props.actions.loadStudies(params);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (!_.isEqual(this.props.paginate, newProps.paginate)) {
      this.setState({ paginate: newProps.paginate });
    }
  }

  setPageNumberTextInput(event) { // eslint-disable-line
    debugger;
    const pageStateChange = Object.assign({}, this.state.paginate, { pageInputValue: event.target.value === '' ? '' : parseInt(event.target.value, 10) });
    this.setState({ paginate: pageStateChange });
    if (pageStateChange.pageInputValue === '') return false;
    this.props.actions.loadStudies({ page: pageStateChange.pageInputValue });
  }
  resetPageNumberTextInput() {
    return this.props.paginate.currentPage;
  }


  render() {
    const renderPaginate = !!this.props.paginate;
    let paginateComponent = <div />;// eslint-disable-line
    let headerComponent = <div />;
    if (renderPaginate) {
      paginateComponent = (<Paginate
        paginationParams={this.state.paginate}
        getPage={this.getPage}
        setPageNumberTextInput={this.setPageNumberTextInput}
        resetPageNumberTextInput={this.resetPageNumberTextInput}
        perPageSizes={constants.GRID_PAGE_OPTIONS}
        translations={i18n.t('pagination', { returnObjects: true })}
      />);
    }
    if (this.props.clientDivision) {
      headerComponent = <PageHeader title=“Home Page“ caption={this.props.clientDivision.name} />;
    }
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {headerComponent}
        <div className="table-container list-container">
          <HomeListPage studies={this.props.studies} clientDivision={this.props.clientDivision} />
          {paginateComponent}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
HomePage.propTypes = {
  studies: React.PropTypes.any,// eslint-disable-line
  paginate: React.PropTypes.any,// eslint-disable-line
  actions: React.PropTypes.any// eslint-disable-line
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  studies: state.studies.studies,
  paginate: state.studies.paginate,
  appPermissions: state.permissions.appPermissions
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(HomeActions, dispatch)
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

Comment: Can you please post relevant excerpt from your `HomePage` component

Comment: @nitte93user3232918 I have added the code for home page component.. can you please help?

Comment: I am not sure how to pass the all those properties listed in prop types to the HomePage component

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when I forgot to export one of my components or I imported one of my components incorrectly.

ex:

```
import HomeListPage from './HomeListPage'
```

Will fail to import correctly if it is not the default export in the HomeListPage file. Your HomePage is correct. Check your other components that you import and make sure they are the default export in their files. You can also import a non-default export with

```
import { HomeListPage } from './HomeListPage'
```

Comment: I am exporting all the related components by default. This home page component is used with react-redux connect function. I am not sure how to pass props to this kind of implementation. @brandon-roberts

Comment: I am not seeing any indication that passing the props is the problem. What leads you to believe that passing props causes the error you are seeing?

Comment: I am passing the props to HomePage component as below and when I am logging it in HomePage constructor function, I dont see the properties I passed. Not sure why ?
TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
                <Provider store={_store} >
                  <HomePage { ...props } />
                </Provider>
              );

Comment: I am not sure why that is the case. Here is a JSBin I mocked up: http://jsbin.com/gugopen/edit?js,console,output. It works as expected (the props are passed all the way into the child component). Can you look and see if you can find a major difference. Also, did you make sure the {...props} you have is the correct object?

Comment: In your example, you have not connected the react component with redux, in my case I have exported like export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);